# Encyclopedia Hinduism Archived

Tags: book-recommendation

[Encyclopedia Hinduism Archived](https://archive.org/details/illustratedencyc0000loch)

Comment: What is the question? You need to post a question :D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to advertise a certain link

Comment: Can't even read the full book its protected XD